# How to find IP of ssh connection in kernel code?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I want to find out IP of ssh connection using kernel code. However, I'm unable to find any suitable reference on Internet.

I tried using usermodehelper API but it seems it doesn't provide the output back in kernel.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: If you are writing a rootkit anyway, just hook the corresponding open syscall ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume 3298 is the pid of the process you are interested in. In userpsace, I can call

```
ls -l /proc/3298/fd
```

It will list something similar like

```
lrwx------ 1 name name 64 Apr  6 11:27 0 -> /dev/pts/2
lrwx------ 1 name name 64 Apr  6 11:27 1 -> /dev/pts/2
lrwx------ 1 name name 64 Apr  6 11:27 2 -> /dev/pts/2
lrwx------ 1 name name 64 Apr  6 11:27 3 -> socket:[50256]
lrwx------ 1 name name 64 Apr  6 11:37 4 -> /dev/pts/2
lrwx------ 1 name name 64 Apr  6 11:37 5 -> /dev/pts/2
lrwx------ 1 name name 64 Apr  6 11:37 6 -> /dev/pts/2
```

We now know that fd 3 (and only fd 3) is the file descriptor you are looking for. Your information should be in fd 3. You should be able to do the same thing in kernelspace by looking at the kernel sources how  /proc/pid/fd is implemented.